# How do I manually call a SEL_MenuHandler

Tags: c++, cocos2d-x, ccmenuitem

I understand that a CCMenuItem has a `CCObject* rec` and a `SEL_MenuHandler selector` and that it will call them when selected but I'd like to know if, given just those two variables, I can manually call them myself and, if so, how?

I'm aware of CCMenuItem's activate() method, but I'm trying to call it without creating the CCMenuItem.

Answer (score 1):

```
this->yourFunctionName(NULL);
```

or

```
rec->*selector(NULL);
```

or

```
rec->*selector(rec); ?
```

not quite sure.

Comment: Which function is that? I only have the `rec` and the `selector`. Can I get this `yourFunctionName` out of either of them?

Comment: @JoshParadroid when you create the menuItem, what did you put into the mene_selector(YOURCLASSNAME::YOURFUNCTIONNAME)?

Comment: I think this is irrelevant. My question is that if, _given just those two variables_ can I manually call them? The menuItem is created elsewhere. I can change my code to take in a menuItem or a function pointer instead if I have to. I'm just wondering if I need to and, if I don't need to, how I can call the selector?

Comment: @JoshParadroid if you check what `menu_selector()` is is doing, actually it is a fucntion Pointer of CCObject::*funtionpointer(CCObject* pObject); you can try `rec->*selector(NULL);`

Comment: That won't compile and gives the error `Called object type 'SEL_MenuHandler' (aka 'void (cocos2d::CCObject::*)(cocos2d::CCObject *)') is not a function or function pointer`

Comment: @JoshParadroid that is wield, what did you set to `selector`, or what is selector = ? when you initialise this variable?, because in CCMenuItem::activate(), this is the way to use it, the original code is `(m_pListener->*m_pfnSelector)(this);` where `m_pListener` is an CCObject* and `m_pfnSelector` is an SEL_MenuHandler.

Comment: @JoshParadroid together with my last comment, but `m_pfnSelecter` must be valid, which means it must pointing to a function which takes an CCObject* as argument. that is why I asked you at the beginning. you have to set the `selector = menu_selecter(YOURCLASS::YOURFUNC);` if your `selector` is SEL_MenuHandler, YOURFUNC must takes an CCObject* as input.

Comment: Thanks for the help, but sadly lack of time prevents me from looking into this further. As a work around, I'm creating a `CCMenuItem` with these parameters and calling activate on it.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried:

```
[rec performSelector:selector];
```

Comment: I don't seem to be able to find this method for a CCObject in Cocos2d-x(2.0.3).